# Simulating an orbit - numerically solving $M(E) = E + \sin(E)$

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Well for a given kepler orbit (which is a ellipse) $0 \leq e < 1$. There are several functions to describe the motion of an object.

$$r(\nu) = \frac{a (1 - e^2)}{1 + e \cos(\nu)}$$
Where $a$ is the semi major axis, $e$ the eccentricity, $\nu$ the true anomaly. And $r$ the distance from the focus point.

One of the basic functions is to use the mean anomaly $M$. The mean anomaly is an object is basically defined as an angle that grows linearly with time ($n$, dependent on the orbital period)
$$M(t) = M_0 + nt$$

The mean anomaly can be expressed as a function of the eccentric anomaly ($E$) as:
$$M = E - e \sin(E)$$
The problem is quite obvious now: the mean anomaly doesn't represent any geometric value, and to convert it to one, a function has to be solved numerically. (Simple geometry allows conversion of $E$ to and from $\nu$).

Now using a method such as Newton's this can be solved - and luckily the mean anomaly doesn't depend on the eccentric anomaly so the truncation error isn't that important.

However I wonder if there is a more clever way, considering the derivatives are very well defined:

$$M'(E) = 1-e\cos(E)$$
$$M''(E) = e\sin(E)$$
$$M'''(E) = e\cos(E)$$
$$M^4(E) = -e\sin(E)$$

And this repeats onwards then. So can a method with a better convergence rate than newton's method be described for this problem?
And further more ($E_0$ means start of the root finding algorithm) - is initializing as follow good (will it guaranteed converge):
$$E_0 = M$$
-Starting the root finding at by stating the mean anomaly is equal to the eccentric anomaly, which is the case for the apo/periapsis.

Comment: A question: Why is this better than simply solving f=ma ?

Comment: @grdgfgr - This *is* the solution of $f=ma$. However solving that leads to a second order differential equation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit#Mathematical_solution_of_the_differential_equation_.281.29_above However solving it further (to actually get the position vector) will give a different system where you have inaccuracies thanks to non infinitelly small time steps. Introducing mean anomaly solves this by keeping sure the orbit shape doesn't change.

Comment: what is wrong with a general non-linear solver?

Comment: Well as I said: I'd use newton's method. However I really need to proof convergence in this case as I don't want my method to not converge. (And if it doesn't I need a way to know when it won't converge and then fall back to another method).

Comment: Halley's method will converge faster than Newton's method. Also, guaranteed convergence is easy to achieve if you first reduce $M$ modulo $2\pi$, so that only $[0,2\pi)$ needs to be considered.

Comment: @Kirill Hmm is there any proof for that guaranteed convergence? I'd love to see that.

Comment: @paul23 No, I meant you can prove it yourself. Another option is to define a solution $E_n(M)$ using Newton's method, and then apply Chebyshev interpolation to $E_n(M)$ to achieve a faster way of evaluating it. In general, see any upper-level numerical analysis textbook.

Comment: There is a whole book devoted to such a problem: Colwell - Solving Keplers Equations Over three Centuries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your post addresses two points

- convergence of Newton method
- methods converging faster than Newton method

Concerning the first point, assuming the starting point to be "reasonable", Newton method would converge without any overshoot of the solution if $$M(E_0) M''(E_0) >0$$ (if I properly remember, this was established by Darboux).

Concerning methods converging faster, the simplest would be Halley (cubic convergence) or Householder (quartic convergence).

Higher order schemes have been proposed (have a look at http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html)

For illustration purposes, let us use $e=5$ and $E_0=3$.

Newton iterates will be $$E_1=2.61438412994111$$ $$E_2=2.59582212992534$$ $$E_3=2.59573908134712$$ $$E_4=2.59573907964980$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

Halley iterates will be $$E_1=2.60556706231111$$ $$E_2=2.59573931852909$$ $$E_3=2.59573907964980$$

Householder iterates will be $$E_1=2.59642488378724$$ $$E_2=2.59573907964981$$

**Edit**

By the way, for a good estimate of the solution, you could use the splendid 1400 year old approximation $$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}$$  proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician. Then, the estimate is just obtained at the price of a quadratic equation. Applied to $e=5$, this would give $E_0=2.5956$ from which convergence will be almost immediate.

Answer (score 1):

You can express $E$ as a series in powers of $e$ using the Lagrange reversion formula:

$$ E = M + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^k}{k!} \left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial M}\right)^{k-1} \sin^k(M) $$

Comment: Hmm that look good. However it doesn't really give a numerical solution just there right? - As we can't sum up to infinity, I'll have to figure a cut-off. How does this depend on a cut-off?

Comment: There are more sophisticated numerical summation methods than fixed cut-offs.  But basically you can try to bound the terms and estimate the tail of the series.